# C++ Phone Book - User Input Into Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm very new at C++ and I am having trouble with my phone book program.

The issue is when I go to add a contact, it saves the name and number in the arrays. If I choose switch case 2 after adding each contact, it'll list all the contacts and phone numbers normally. But if I select switch case 1 multiple times in a row and add more than one contact before I select switch case 2 to display all the contacts, it will only print the most recent contact I added.

The code is unfinished, but I can't seem to figure this one out! When I add more than one contact at a time, does it override the most recent one I just added? Sorry if I am not explaining this well, I'm not yet familiar with all the proper terminology!

I also don't want to use a loop for the input, so the user will not have to input ten names and numbers all at once if they don't want to. Unless there's a way to use a loop and have them end it after a certain amount of entries.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    string nameArray[10];
    string numberArray[10];
    int arraySize = 10;
    int index;
    int i;

void addContact() {
    // Get user input
    cout << "\n\tEnter contact information" << endl;
    cout << "\t==========================" << endl;
    cout << "\tEnter name: ";
    getline(cin, nameArray[i]);
    cout << "\tEnter phone number: ";
    cin >> numberArray[i];
    cin.ignore();
}

void viewAll() {
    // Declare variables
    int pass = -1;
    string tempNumber = "";
    string tempName = "";
    
    // Sort array in ascending order
    for(pass=0; pass<9; pass++) {
        for(index = 0; index < (9 - pass); index++) {
            if(nameArray[index] > nameArray[index + 1]) {
                tempName = nameArray[index];
                nameArray[index] = nameArray[index + 1];
                nameArray[index + 1] = tempName;
                tempNumber = numberArray[index];
                numberArray[index] = numberArray[index + 1];
                numberArray[index + 1] = tempNumber;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Print contacts after sort
    cout << endl;
    for(int j=0; j<arraySize; j++) {
        cout << '\t' << nameArray[j] << '\t' << '\t' << numberArray[j] << endl;
    }
}

void searchContact() {

}

void editContact() {
    
}

void deleteContact() {
    
}

int main() {
    int choice;
    while(1) {
        cout << "\n\t\tMAIN MENU" << endl;
        cout << "\t=======================" << endl;
        cout << "\t [1] Add Contact" << endl;
        cout << "\t [2] View All Contacts" << endl;
        cout << "\t [3] Search Contact" << endl;
        cout << "\t [4] Edit Contact" << endl;
        cout << "\t [5] Delete Contact" << endl;
        cout << "\t [6] Exit Program" << endl;
        cout << "\t=======================" << endl;
        cout << '\t';
        cin >> choice;
        
        switch(choice) {
            case 1: // Add a new contact
                cin.ignore();
                addContact();
                break;
            case 2: // Print all contacts in alphabetical order
                viewAll();
                break;
            case 3: // Search and print contact name and phone number
                searchContact();
                break;
            case 4: // Edit a contact
                editContact();
                break;
            case 5: // Delete a contact
                deleteContact();
                break;
            case 6: // End program
                return 0;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "\nInvalid choice." << endl;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you increment `i` anywhere.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to assign string variables to "" when you declare them.  The `std::string` initializes itself to empty by default.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are are using separate arrays for the different types of values, instead of using a single array of a struct/class type?  Is there a reason why you are not using a standard container, like `std::vector`, that handles the complexities of array management for you?

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector` instead of arrays.  Arrays can overflow and **you** will need to manage the memory.  The `std::vector` will grow during runtime as necessary.

Comment: I am in an intro class and we haven't learned vectors yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think [Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp) has given you the correct answer, but you said your new so i'd like to give you a slightly longer explanation, and a little bonus advice.

Consider your `addContact` function. You ask for values to be inserted into the name and numbers array at position i. You need to update that position after you add a contact or it will simply overwrite what was there previously. So a `++i;` at the end of the function will solve your problem as this means next time you add a contact it goes to the next slot in the array. Now be mindful of this as your array only has (right now) 10 items in it, so once you add 10 entries `i` will have a value of 10 now which if you try to do `nameArray[i]` it would be trying to access, or worse write to, the 11th item in your array which does not exist, this is very bad (take a quick google tour of "buffer overflow error"). So make sure you add a safety check in at the start of `addContact` that checks if `i == 10` in which case you could for example: print an error message then  return from the function immediately. Definately DO NOT try to access an element of the array that does not exist.

I would also recommend explicitly initialising i to 0 just for clarity (it will be 0 because it is a global variable, but it would not be 0 if it was declared inside a function, so its a good habit to get into)

Finally, you seem to be using a mix of declaring a loop variable outside of the loop `for(pass=0;...)` and declaring it inside the loop `for(int y = 0;...)` from what i can see you dont use the variables declared outside of the loop like `pass` or `index` for anything except looping, so consider declaring them in the loop where they are used, this just keeps things a bit tidier and avoids mistakes where because the variable is still in scope someone might think its valid to use it as an array index or the likes.

Hope thats useful.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you so much!!!!!!! I could cry right now